# I really think this should be removed from the review audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/8413873

Although I did pass it because it looked strange to me and I went to the question and saw it upvoted, so I clearly identified it as a review audit, I really think this clearly have some points that could probably put it on the line between a bad answer and "not an answer".

1. It does refer to a comment on the question, I even had to make a search on the post to understand it.
2. The fix is downgrading some SDK tends to look like a strange solution for me, on any question. And it seems even stranger provided the fact that the actual said SDK version used is not even provided in the question.
3. The phrasing of the answer could get a lift "see this provided above by CommonsWare" at first glance I was like : "is there a missing link on the word 'this' ?"

Any thoughts ?

Comment: actually I did look at the whole thread right now, 3 answer saying the exact same thing (downgrade) and even one question as an answer...

Comment: That answer got 12 upvotes where other answers saying same did not got any upvote.suspicious

Comment: Suspicious that the first useful answer gets more votes than late, redundant answers, @Shaiful?

Comment: I agree useful answer get more votes.Other answer telling same but no-votes so, I just suspect.May be I am wrong.

Comment: I'd be suspicious too, if the other answers were posted first or even shortly after - but there's over half a week between the first answer and the next, with many views and votes during that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grammar was a bit awkward. Otherwise, I don't see a problem with it; clearly, this is a problem that's been affecting a lot of people recently, and the answer has been useful - if reviewers are unable to figure this out, they're better off not reviewing for a bit.

Editing to fix the grammar is fine though. And would've passed the audit as well.

Comment: But then what in the case that @Shaiful stated in comments (but removed) if the comment is removed, part of the answer does not makes sens anymore, and we are left with "kind of" a link answer. Aren't we ? Shouldn't have the the user quoted that comment in his answer (and give credit to the user commenting ?)

Comment: @b.enoit.be I commented that thinking same as you said.But latter I saw the whole thread and realized the answer is not wrong(that's why I delete my comment) but agree he should include the part of the comment into the answer.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam please remember that an audit is **not** about answer being technically right or not, I'm not an android dev so I'm not, and even cannot make a stand on that. What I can say, in the other hand is, by the phrasing of it, and when having just the question and this answer in the review queue my first move would have been to call it "not an answer".

Comment: Because for me an answer would be : 'you have to downgrade because the foo is not in the bar in this version and to downgrade you have to do this and that and... (which actually is only standing is the said comment).'

Comment: The critical part of the answer is the last sentence, @b.enoit.be - and that's valid regardless of whether the comment stays or goes. I assume the author included the first part just to give credit.

Comment: And what about the fact that the solution is 'downgrade' when the version used is not in the question in the first place ? Could we please remember here that in the review queue audit we do not see either the comment on the original post either the real answerer name ?